# Is it safe to send SHA 1 fingerprint of signing certificate as part api key verification in GCP api gateway?

Tags: android, google-cloud-functions, sha1, api-key, google-cloud-api-gateway

To secure and monitor our GCP cloud functions we integrated the GCP api gateway .

The android app has to pass the SHA1 fingerprint, package name and the api key as part of the request to get authenticated.

Is it safe to do this way?

https://cloud.google.com/api-keys/docs/add-restrictions-api-keys

https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/api-keys#api_key_restrictions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer this question, you can ask yourselves: Is someone can decompile my APK and extract the API key and the sha-1 from my code?

Sadly, yes...

Thus, this is enough to make the assumption that's your app which make the request, but you need to add a dedicated authentication mechanism to authenticate the users (firebase auth)

Finally, all depends on is it safe **for what**?

Comment: Google maps subscription seems to be working in this same way ,sending api key request from the app and MAPS SDK inside the app will take care of getting SHA1 and package name while sending the request.

If implemented as you suggested, Can go with firebase auth alone . api gateway is not required .This is an overhead in terms of adding api key restriction and authenticating using other mechanisms like firebase auth.

Comment: Keep in mind that the API key is designed to know "who will pay" for the request and not to ensure authentication and authorization.

Comment: is adding api key restrictions is not the whole point of security apart form who will pay? At least it is how it is mentioned in the api gateway apps securing api gateway with the api key restrictions.

Comment: You restrict the use of the API key to a context, a scope of usage (you need to provide the SHA-1 of your certificates, you can also set a list of host domain, or a list of authorized IP). But, if someone is able to generate request with the same parameter, in another context (and it's possible because, at the end, it's only char strings!), your security is down.